# Ideas for versatile clothes in northern India

Tags: india, gear

I will be heading to Ladakh (Leh included) from mid-August to mid-October, but I want to travel with only a 32 liter bag, and obviously I will have to be flexible with my gear due to the difference of temperatures there as well as in the rest of India. I will eventually be passing from other places too.

Any tips on how to choose versatile clothing space-wise?

Comment: Would you like to carry any Indian styled clothing with you?

Comment: I could do. if it makes me warm when is cold and fits in the bag!

Answer (score 5):

Since you specifically mentioned Leh/Ladakh I would like to mention a specific garment which *any* traveler should buy or carry there. It's a [Pashmina Shawl/Wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashmina)! They are relatively quite light and surprisingly very warm. They are relatively exotic to Ladakh as well. It would not only be useful but would make a great souvenir. They are a delicacy in other parts of India as well but should be relatively cheaper in Ladakh.

The pashmina shawl should take care of you at any point of time during the cold. [Accuweather](http://www.accuweather.com/en/in/leh/359172/month/359172?monyr=10/01/2014) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leh#Climate) tell me that the temperature of Leh should not go below 0°C for the duration of your stay.

Including this, for other periods of time a light windcheater which can be easily folded would be suitable.

This should take care of any temperatures >0°C quite easily. If you plan to go high up in the mountains, you should consider a heavier wool jacket.

Except this, you can carry regular clothes just like you would normally for a temperature of 25-30°C.

Comment: nice! did not know if this garment. i will go and do my research right away. thanks!

Comment: do you know any prices for this? more or less...

Comment: They usually go from around $100 to $300. It depends a lot on where you are buying it. More intricate ones can go as high up as $5000. Here's a link you can [read](http://littleblackbookdelhi.com/1014/real-deal-pashmina)

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Last question on this. I guess the cheaper place to buy it would be Kashmir itself? Leh or any place else? Thanks!

Comment: @Pixie Any of those places would do! Kashmir and Leh both will offer quite competitive prices and lots of variety! Make sure it's an original though!

Comment: A pashmina is vital traveler equipment! Makes any coat warmer, or subs for a sweater, can be a blanket on the plane, or roll it for a pillow, ... everyone should have one.

Comment: came back and yes it was worth buying one.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about versatile clothes, I would simply [buy any necessary warmer clothing when I get there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/is-it-possible-to-buy-outdoor-clothing-in-northern-india-nepal).  Prices are cheap: I paid something like Rs 600 for a "North Face" parka in Dharamsala, and while it was almost certainly a fake, it did its job in keeping me warm.   When it's time to head back to warmer climes, instead of carrying it with you, you can just sell it or pass it on to another traveler.

Comment: No offense buddy, but I assure you that you could have bargained and got it for like 200-300. Those things are usually super cheap and it is true you can buy something "disposable" like that quite easily in India.

Comment: Sure, but that's the *gora* tax, and shivering in the cold when it's pouring rain outside is not a great position for bargaining. ;)  And I ended up bringing it back and still use it on rare occasions, so I've gotten my money's worth!

Comment: Haha. That's true. The *gora* tax is quite common in India. =P